# Unbeatable openings

Tags: opening

I am a new chess player and after some days me and my friends decided to set a chess tournament.
.
As i am new to chess, I want some unbeatable (read: solid and sensible) openings so I can beat my friends in chess games.
.
.
Please give me some best openings.
.
.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Well, the quick answer is... there aren't any. If there were any unbeatable openings, Chess wouldn't be much of a game, would it? If you refine this question a bit (do you want some opening traps? Generally solid options? Complicated options?) you might get some more useful info.

Comment: Unbeatable means hard to break......

Comment: If you're really brand new, the specific opening you play is probably irrelevant. Games at that very low levels are almost always decided by large mistakes--overlooking threats and such. If you give us a better idea of your skill level (maybe post a PGN of a recent game where you feel you played well), we'll be able to help more.

Comment: how can it be hard to break an opening if it is played by a person who can not play? Just think for a little bit whether you question can have any meaning: if winning people would be as easy as asking 3 sentence question on forum and learning an opening for few hours, why would not anyone be a GM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Henry's comment above that your opening choice won't be the deciding factor, choosing a good opening will probably help you.

Regarding openings:

1. Don't just memorize moves.
2. If you don't understand it, don't play it.  This doesn't mean you have an encyclopedic knowledge, but avoid rote moves.  The reason is that your opponent can choose a move for which you're not prepared.  If you're only memorizing you'll be lost.  But if you know why you're doing what you're doing, you have a better chance to respond effectively.

You need one opening as White, and one or two as Black.

For White, a common opening is the 'King Pawn's Game". This opening makes it easy for you 1. develop your pieces, and 2. castle your king to make it safe.

Here's how it goes:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.Nc3 Nf6 5.O-O
```

By the 5th move, White is developing nicely and has castled. Black is doing ok too, but for now, get your pieces developed. Perhaps your opponent won't make such prudent choices.

For Black, you'll need 2 openings, one against e4 and one against d4.  I'll let someone else go into more detail, but consider the Caro-Kann against e4.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is important to work on your openings and get a decent opening repertoire. The best move for a beginner would be 1.e4 as Whites. Then you should consider all responds from Black to your first move. Main variations will be:
1. - e5
1. - e6
1. - c5
1. - c6
1. - d6
1. - d5
1. - Nf6
1. - Nc6

All these moves lead to totally different middle games therefore you need know some main variations for all these openings. It would be good if you also find out respective games played by world-class GMs so you can better understand the following middlegames. Chessbase has got all the games you want. The same counts for Black repertoire. You need to consider what will you respond to:
1. e4
1. d4
1. c4
1. Nf3
1. g3

It needs to be said that many start moves can lead to the same openings with different move orders. For example, you can play King's Indian as Black against 1. d4, 1. c4, 1. g3 and 1. Nf3. It will also depend on you opponent's moves.